# Python/pyserial cx_freeze Compilation error: no module named tools

Tags: python-2.7, cx-freeze, pyserial

I am trying to compile a python code with cx_freeze in Windows 7, python 2.7, but it keeps giving me trouble because of pyserial. I tried to import the pyserial tools module in many different ways but I keep getting compilation errors:

```
import serial
import serial.tools
from serial.tools import list_ports

#I also tried:
#import serial.tools.list_ports
#from serial import tools
#import serial.tools.list_ports
#from serial import tools
```

The error message varies between:
ImportError: No module named tools
and
ImportError: No module named tools.list_ports

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: It seems that pySerial is not installed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am sure that pySerial is installed. I can read/write to com ports without a problem. The issues appears when I try to compile the code with cx_freeze. Before that there is no error message.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of Python, pySerial is, probably, not installed for version you currently use. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-install-a-module-use-pip-for-specific-version-of) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991193/installing-modules-for-multiple-python-versions). If it worked in current version, maybe, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15622021/5510499) helps. If nothing helps, try to reinstall pySerial.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I just solved the issue. Turns out that pySerial was installed from a different directory and somehow cx_freeze was not finding it. I simply copied the whole serial directory to: "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\"  and the problem has been solved.